# Replace a part of a file path in a string field with SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello I have a table `Gallery` with a field `url_immagine` and I would like to use a query to replace all values that look like  `upload/gallery/311/ge_c1966615153f6b2fcf5d84c1e389eea8.jpg` in `/ge_c1966615153f6b2fcf5d84c1e389eea8.jpg`

Unfortunately the a part of the string, the ID (331) is not always the same and therefore can not understand how ... 
I tried the regular expression like this:

```
 UPDATE gallery SET url_immagine = replace(url_immagine, 'upload/gallery/.*/', '/')
```

but it seem not to work.

Comment: Which value are you trying to replace?

Comment: @McAdam331 I tried with `update gallery set url_immagine = replace(url_immagine, 'upload/gallery/.*/', '/')`

Comment: So you're trying to replace the entire string? Why not just do `SET url_immagine = '/'`?

Comment: SQL can be used for mass destruction, you don't need an ID, a single query can change the whole table.

Comment: because the entire line is: `upload/gallery/311/ge_c1966615153f6b2fcf5d84c1e389eea8.jpg` and I want to keep only `/ge_c1966615153f6b2fcf5d84c1e389eea8.jpg`

Comment: than you should update your question, so that people don't downvote it.

Comment: I have edited your question with the information from your comments to make it easier to see what you have asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combine CONCAT and SUBSTRING_INDEX since you can use last index of "/"

```
UPDATE gallery
SET url_immagine = (SELECT CONCAT('/',SUBSTRING_INDEX(url_immagine, '/', -1)));
```

Try that to confirm it's doing what you want :

```
SELECT CONCAT('/',SUBSTRING_INDEX(url_immagine, '/', -1))
FROM gallery
```

Comment: hello I used the CONCAT and yes, the result is that I would like to receive, unfortunately, if I use the string you gave me error... `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT CONCAT('/',SUBSTRING_INDEX(url_immagine, '/', -1))' at line 2 `

Answer (score 0):

You can see documentation for the replace function and all other string functions in the mysql manual:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_replace

It does not mention that replace handles regular expressions, so we an assume it does not, and it is working verbatim and uses the your `*` to look for the char `*`.

You see also that there seem not to be a function that does the whole job for you. So you must somehow combine them. The idea of Mateo is probably the right direction.